# External javascript(jQuery) file could not be import in react js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I have write a document ready event in my external script file. And i have include it in my index.html file using `<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/script.js"` But the events not triggered even the file path is correct.

If i put my script code in index.html using `<script> //my code </script>` the event working properly after browser loading the page. But if i redirect to another page using react-router the event not working.

I am using

React 16.3.2

JQuery 2.2.4

Thanks in advance

Comment: `I have to write a document ready event in my external script file` - jQuery's `document.ready` isn't some magic thing that can't be replicated - it's simply an event listener on `DOMContentLoaded`. Seems ridiculous to include the library (or any part thereof) simply for `document.addEventListner('DOMContentLoaded',yourFn)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually using jquery with a react app is not a good idea but even so,
did you try using "[defer](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp)" attribute?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/script.js" defer>
```

and if you want to call your method on every client side page load you should implement something like this:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

//Your initialization

browserHistory.listen( location =>  {
 //Do your stuff here
});
```

wrap all your codes with a function and call it in the listener.